# Generate bounded numbers with approximately skewed normal distribution

Tags: r, normal-distribution, skewness

[Possible duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2480415/generating-random-numbers-with-a-skewed-distribution-with-many-possible-values)

I'm trying to generate `n` numbers, each of which lies between `[1,m]` (where `m` is an integer), such that their frequency roughly follows a skewed normal distribution.

So far I have been able use the `fGarch` package and generate a skewed normal distribution with:

```
library(fGarch)
r = rsnorm(n=1000, mean = 20, sd = 15, xi=2)
plot(density(r))
```

but I cannot set lower and upper limits on the numbers.
Is there a way I can ensure that the numbers are bounded but also *approximate* a skewed normal distribution?

**UPDATE:** I am trying to model the number of books n people read, given a set of m books in the universe. Skewed normal because empirical data of most media consumption suggests that actual consumption patterns are positively skewed, while survey self-reports suggest the patterns are negatively skewed. Consumption patterns are rarely normally distributed.

Comment: First of all, you should explain why you need this. Then your issue is ill-defined. Why the skewed normal? Why is roughly following sufficient? Do you only have the limits or also the distribution parameters? Is this a truncated distribution?

Comment: One idea might be rejection sampling. Another idea could be using a skewed distribution with natural limits and scaling the result such as `r1 <- rbeta(1000, 1, 3); m <- 50; r1 <- r1 * (m - 1) + 1; hist(r1, breaks = 50)`.

Comment: @Roland, I've added the explanation and the context. Thanks, scaling seems a good idea.

Comment: Not using the Poisson distribution or the negative binomial distribution when modelling a count variable seems strange. I'd assume that you should at least use a discrete distribution.

Comment: @Roland but those wouldn't give me a distribution that looks like what I need, would it?

Comment: "Number of books read" does not suggest anything like a normal distribution, I would guess a distribution having a long and heavy upper tail, skewed yes. Do you have some actual data?  some US data indicates an average of 12/year and median of 4/year, indicating a quite skew distribution which a skew-normal would not represent well ...

Comment: @wrahool Well, I'd assume that you use a regression model, which means you only need to define a *conditional* distribution family. I'd assume that skewness would be explained by your predictors.